# Install Python3.10 in a Docker Image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a Docker Image that installs Python3.10. I cannot use the typical `FROM python:3.10-xxx` Image since I have to build on top of someone else's base (`FROM nrel/energyplus:23.2.0`).

So I am attempting to install Python3.10 myself, but so far I am failing completely. Is there a good example of how to properly do something like this in a Dockerfile?

When I include the line:

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip`

in my Dockerfile, I get this asking for user input:

```
 => [app 2/9] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip                                          265.7s
 => => #   1. Africa        6. Asia            11. System V timezones                                                        
 => => #   2. America       7. Atlantic Ocean  12. US                                                                        
 => => #   3. Antarctica    8. Europe          13. None of the above                                                         
 => => #   4. Australia     9. Indian Ocean                                                                                  
 => => #   5. Arctic Ocean  10. Pacific Ocean                                                                                
 => => # Geographic area:
```

which then just stops the build. Is this the correct way to install Python3.10 in an Image? Is there way to get past this user-input portion?

Comment: [How to install tzdata on a ubuntu docker image?](https://serverfault.com/a/992421)